# How can we do LDU decomposition modulo $p$?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, finite-fields

If we have an $n \times n$ matrix, with all entries taken modulo $p$, how can we output the three matrixes in LDU decomposition, with all entries again modulo $p$?  We can assume the input matrix is invertible.

That is, $LDU=A$, with $A$ given.  $L$ is a lower-triangular matrix, $D$ is a diagonal matrix, and $U$ is an upper-triangular matrix.  The entries of the results are modulo $p$.

Comment: Do `LUDecomposition[mat,Modulus->p]` and separate out the diagonal from the upper part.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thanks!  That Modulus trick makes it easy!

Comment: Note that `LUDecomposition[]` *pivots*, so you have an extra permutation matrix to contend with. If you need the version without pivoting, you'll have to write your own.

Comment: @J.M. I'm not sure it pivots in the modular case, except when it must. But I don't recall for certain (I think I added that option, and it would have been around 20 years ago).

Comment: @Daniel, yep, here's a random example where it pivots: `LUDecomposition[{{4, 4, 4, 3}, {0, 0, 4, 1}, {3, 3, 4, 2}, {4, 1, 0, 4}}, Modulus -> 5]` But that would be because the leading $2\times 2$ block is singular, which is exactly when pivoting is necessary.

Comment: @J.M Yes, that's what I meant by "except when it must".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, here is how to generate a modular $\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf U$ decomposition, as suggested by Daniel in the comments:

```
mat = {{1, 0, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 1, 2}}; m = 5;
{lu, piv, cond} = LUDecomposition[mat, Modulus -> m];

l = LowerTriangularize[lu, -1] + IdentityMatrix[Length[lu]];
d = DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[lu]];
u = Mod[DiagonalMatrix[PowerMod[Diagonal[lu], -1, m]].UpperTriangularize[lu], m];
```

You can check that `Mod[l.d.u, m]` gives a result that is congruent to `mat`. If the matrix has a singular leading submatrix, one should then account for an additional permutation matrix constructed from the vector `piv`; how to do this is left as an exercise for the interested reader.